# Boot Vista x64 with both ICH8 and ICH10 AHCI support

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, sata, ahci

I have a situation where I need to boot Windows Vista 64-bit from both a ICH10 and ICH8 AHCI SATA controller.  Currently, it is setup to boot from the ICH10, but when I try booting with the ICH8, I get the famed Windows STOP 7B BSOD.  How can I add the ICH8 driver so that I can work around this BSOD and boot the system?

I have updated to the latest Intel AHCI driver (8.9.0.1023 as of this post) which is supposed to support both chipsets, but I feel I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question, I upgraded my machine to Windows 7 64-bit with a fresh install.  Additionally, I updated VirtualBox under both Windows and Linux to version 3.1.2.  I am now able to boot Linux in VirtualBox hosted under Windows 7 and boot Windows 7 as a guest under a Linux host on the same machine.  Pretty cool!

Windows 7 resolved this issue for me.  It detected the change of Mass Storage controller, configured it, and began installing the other VirtualBox drivers, all on the first boot under VirtualBox.  When I restart into Windows natively, it has no trouble booting as it used to.

To summarize, the solution was to updated to Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can boot from both as hard drive chipset / logic chip is one of the unique features between installations of Windows.

I would not think it is possible to switch between them without doing a sysprep generalise, or reinstall windows.

Comment: If this is true, then why am I able to switch the ICH10 controller from AHCI mode to RAID mode and still boot?  The AHCI controller and RAID controllers have different PnP ids (therefore are seen differently by the OS) even though they use the same iaStor.sys as the driver.

I don't mean to discount your answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am confused here - so, ICH10 is in AHCI mode and when you switch to ICH8-RAID, it still boots, but then when you switch back it no longer works? or have I got this wrong? I am having a real hard time trying to understand this!

Comment: When ICH10 is in AHCI mode, Vista boots.  When ICH10 is in RAID mode, it boots.  When I use ICH8 in AHCI mode it no longer boots and dies with a STOP 7B BSOD.  My hypothesis is that I should be able to add support for the ICH8 in AHCI mode because I can boot my ICH10 in both AHCI and RAID mode, which appear as different mass storage devices to the OS.

Comment: I would have thought that it is irrelevant as AHCI and RAID are a mode of ICH10 which is the driver that is loaded - ICH8 is a completely separate driver.... If I can ask, why do you even want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to cross-virtualize Windows and Linux, meaning, boot into Windows and access my Linux install (which I have working) and boot into Linux and access my Windows side.  I need to add support for both ICH8 and ICH10 because my hardware has an ICH10 chipset and VirtualBox uses ICH8 emulation.

As for ICH8 being a completely separate driver, picking apart the INFs of ICH10 drivers downloaded from Intel, they appear to still support ICH8.  But clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the Intel driver and use the standard Microsoft AHCI driver. It should support both controllers.